Python 3.12.3 Quart Hypercorn Error in ASGI Framework RuntimeError: no running event loop
I run a quart hypercorn server with the following command:
pipenv run hypercorn --config=hypercorn.toml --reload src.main:app

and the following configuration:
accesslog = "/var/log/pythonrestapi"
errorlog = "/var/log/pythonrestapi"
alt_svc_headers = ["h3=\":443\"; ma=3600, h3-29=\":443\"; ma=3600"]
quic_bind = "0.0.0.0:4433"
bind = "0.0.0.0:4433"
insecure_bind = "0.0.0.0:8080"
certfile = "server.crt"
keyfile = "server.key"
#server_names = ["pythonrestapi"]
worker_class = "trio"

and hit the following error:
2024-05-29 13:31:33 INFO     Running on https://0.0.0.0:4433 (CTRL + C to quit)
2024-05-29 13:31:33 INFO     Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080 (CTRL + C to quit)
2024-05-29 13:31:34 INFO     Running on https://0.0.0.0:4433 (QUIC) (CTRL + C to quit)
2024-05-29 13:33:09 ERROR    Error in ASGI Framework
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/khteh/.local/share/virtualenvs/PythonRestAPI-6TwrpjXm/lib/python3.12/site-packages/hypercorn/trio/task_group.py", line 26, in _handle
    await app(scope, receive, send, sync_spawn, call_soon)
  File "/home/khteh/.local/share/virtualenvs/PythonRestAPI-6TwrpjXm/lib/python3.12/site-packages/hypercorn/app_wrappers.py", line 34, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/khteh/.local/share/virtualenvs/PythonRestAPI-6TwrpjXm/lib/python3.12/site-packages/quart/app.py", line 1667, in __call__
    await self.asgi_app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/khteh/.local/share/virtualenvs/PythonRestAPI-6TwrpjXm/lib/python3.12/site-packages/quart/app.py", line 1693, in asgi_app
    await asgi_handler(receive, send)
  File "/home/khteh/.local/share/virtualenvs/PythonRestAPI-6TwrpjXm/lib/python3.12/site-packages/quart/asgi.py", line 48, in __call__
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/asyncio/tasks.py", line 463, in wait
    loop = events.get_running_loop()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: no running event loop

src/main.py:
from src.app import create_app
app = create_app()
app = cors(app, allow_credentials=True, allow_origin="https://localhost:4433")
Healthz(app, no_log=True)
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
bcrypt.init_app(app)

src/app.py:
def create_app() -> Quart:
    """
    Create App
    """
    # App initialization
    app = Quart(__name__, template_folder='view/templates', static_url_path='', static_folder='view/static')
    app.config.from_file("/etc/pythonrestapi_config.json", json.load)
    if "SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI" not in app.config:
        app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = f"postgresql://{os.getenv('POSTGRESQL_USER')}:{os.getenv('POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD')}@svc-postgresql/library"
    app.register_blueprint(home_blueprint, url_prefix="/")
    app.register_blueprint(fibonacci_blueprint, url_prefix="/fibonacci")
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint, url_prefix="/auth")
    app.register_blueprint(user_blueprint, url_prefix="/users")
    app.register_blueprint(author_blueprint, url_prefix="/authors")
    app.register_blueprint(book_blueprint, url_prefix="/books")
    db.init_app(app)
    return app


You are using Hypercorn with worker_class = "trio" which means it will switch to using the trio event loop. Quart expects the asyncio event loop to be used, hence the error. If you want to use the trio event loop then switch Quart for Quart-Trio

I don't know what's the difference between trio and asyncio, I switched to worker_class = "asyncio" but to no avail.

You must get a different error with the asyncio worker though, what is the error? The workers are documented here

https://github.com/pgjones/hypercorn/issues/182
